# 64 bit warning/error : incompatible pointer types passing "**int" to parameter of type 'unsigned int'

Tags: objective-c, ios7, 64-bit, exc-bad-access

I wrote this method and when I run on arhitecture on 32bit everything is fine, but when I run project on 64Bit I receive warnings and my application crash with error : "Exc_bad_access (code=1 address=0x0)".

This is my method :

```
  + (NSArray*) getFieldsForClass:(Class)class
{
    static NSCharacterSet* commaset;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        commaset = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@","];
    });
    NSUInteger *raw_propertyCount;
    objc_property_t* raw_properties = class_copyPropertyList(class, &raw_propertyCount);
    NSMutableArray* properties = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i=0; i<raw_propertyCount; i++) {
        NSString* propertyName = [NSString stringWithCString:property_getName(raw_properties[i]) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [properties addObject:propertyName];
    }
    free(raw_properties);
    return properties;
}
```

Application crash at this line :

> NSString* propertyName = [NSString
>   stringWithCString:property_getName(raw_properties[i])
>   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Can you help me to fix this crash, please ?
  Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
objc_property_t * class_copyPropertyList(Class cls, unsigned int *outCount)
```

expects a pointer to an `unsigned int` as last argument, therefore you have to replace

```
NSUInteger *raw_propertyCount;
```

by

```
unsigned int raw_propertyCount;
```

On the 32-bit iOS platform, a pointer and an int have the same size, therefore it
worked just by chance.